# angularjs - ng-repeat works with $index only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and I have to say I am finding it exceedingly difficult and fiddly.

I have a json response from a webserver. Typical array of dictionaries. I want to display the `name` key for each dictionary in the `values` array. This works:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-model="projects" ng-repeat="values in projects">
    project name:{{projects.values[$index].name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This does NOT work, but I don't understand why it doesn't:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-model="projects" ng-repeat="values in projects">
    project name:{{values.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Plain old `{{name}}` doesn't work either.  None of the examples I've found resort to calling out the array index explicitly with `$index`, so I must be doing something wrong. Please enlighten me!

Comment: can you share project json?

Comment: $index is the index of the <li> list item, which (especially if you apply a filter) will not always correspond to the index of the object you are iterating,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need ng-model on your list anywhere.

here is a working example of what you're trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/8r2zA/1/

and as the others said, if you need access to the index in your iteration you can do:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(index, values) in projects">
    {{projects[index].name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer got me the closest:     `<ul ng-repeat="values in projects.values">
        <li>{{values.name}}</li>
    </ul>`  Seems weird that you have to repeat `values` like that. I thought there was some sort of implicit dictionary being passed to the brackets.

Comment: think of it as a forEach loop. You're basically saying "repeat each VALUE IN the PROJECTS.VALUES array", so although it doesn't actually matter what you call it; it would make more sense for you to call it value (not values). e.g. ng-repeat="value in projects.values". You could call it bacon in projects.values if you wanted to and reference everything in that array using {{bacon.whateverProperty}}

Comment: i'm totally going to call it bacon from now on.

Answer (score -1):

It would be good, to see yours `projects` structure. 
But, you could also try:

```
<li ng-repeat="(index, name) in projects">
  {{name[index]}}
</li>
```